# How do I ensure R Plot in Shiny app is visible?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R coding and I am trying to create a shiny app for my team to use. The idea is that anyone can input an ID number, start and end dates and these inputs will be used as parameters for a SQL query, that will then generate the data for a plot.

The app seems to run within R Studio with the correct inputs, however no plot appears.

```
---
title: "TheoGraph"
format: html
author: "name"
server: shiny
---
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                navbarPage(
                  "Business Intelligence R Application",
                  tabPanel("TheoGraph",
                             sidebarPanel(
                             tags$h3("Input:"),
                             textInput("nhsnumber", "Pseudonimised NHS Number", "1234"),
                             textInput("startdate", "Start Date:", value = "01-APR-2019"),
                             textInput("enddate", "End Date:", value = "30-MAR-2023"),
                             actionButton("submitBtn", "Submit"),
                             style = "background-color: #ADD8E6;"
                           ), # sidebarPanel
                           mainPanel(
                             h1("Header 1"),
                             h4("TheoGraph Output"),
                             verbatimTextOutput("txtout"),
                             plotOutput("plot")
                           ) # mainPanel

                  ) # Navbar 1, tabPanel
                ) # navbarPage
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive values for database connection and result
  con3 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  result <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  # Function to handle SQL query and result`your text`
  executeQuery <- function() {
    # Disconnect if there was a previous connection
    if (!is.null(con3())) {
      dbDisconnect(con3())
      con3(NULL)
    }
    
    # Connect to the database
    con3_val <- DBI::dbConnect(
      odbc::odbc(),
      Driver = "SQL Server",
      Server = "SERVER",
      Database = "DATABASE",
      Trusted_Connection = "True"
    )
    con3(con3_val)
    
# Execute the SQL query
query <- sqlInterpolate(
  con3(),
  "
DECLARE @NHS_NUMBER VARCHAR(50), @START DATE, @END DATE;
SET @NHS_NUMBER = ?;
SET @START = ?;
SET @END = ?;

SELECT DISTINCT 
[NHS_Number] = [A].[ID],
[Setting] = 'Acute',
[Event] = 'A&E Attendance'
[Type] = 'A&E Attendance'
[Date] = [A].[Date]
FROM Table [A]
WHERE [A].[ID] = @NHS_NUMBER
AND CAST([A].[Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@START AS DATE) AND CAST(@END AS DATE)
",
  input$nhsnumber,
  input$startdate,
  input$enddate
)

result_val <- dbGetQuery(con3(), query)
result(result_val)
  
  
  # Observe changes in input and manage database connection and result
  observeEvent(c(input$nhsnumber, input$startdate, input$enddate), {
    executeQuery()
  })
  
  # Close the database connection when the app exits
  observe({
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      if (!is.null(con3())) {
        dbDisconnect(con3())
      }
    })
  })
  
  # Render the output (print)
  output$txtout <- renderPrint({
    print(result())
  })
  
  # Render the output (plot)
# Render the output (print)
output$plot <- renderPrint({
  req(result())  # Ensure that result() is not NULL before attempting to print
  result()
})
  }
   }

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you make a plot appear without the interface?

Comment: FYI, the `"SQL Server"` driver is _ancient_. I suggest that you upgrade your driver to 17 at a minimum, current is 18; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server. (I'm amused to find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/connect-history that includes the text *"The first "SQL Server" ODBC driver still ships as part of Windows Data Access Components. This driver isn't recommended for new development."*) Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files.

Answer (score 1):

Bigger changes:

- anything that uses `input$...` and any reactive value such as `con3` needs to be inside a `reactive` or `observe` block
- you have `observe` and `output$` blocks inside your function, seems that you are missing a close-brace somewhere
- you will be querying every time something in one of the three fields changes, you should probably be triggering on `"submitBtn"` instead of changes in the three fields
- you are trying to `renderPrint` to a plot object `output$plot`, this should be `renderPlot` ... and then you need some plotting function, since `result()` by itself will be a `data.frame` (or `NULL`); I'll write in `someplot(..)`, but that function doesn't exist, you need to write it

A couple of suggested changes, though not mandatory:

- I find `sqlInterpolate` to be palatable (far better than `paste` or `sprintf`), but not the best; I recommend using [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) ala `dbBind` or `dbGetQuery(..., params=)`
- best-practices with functions is that they are either explicitly passed data as arguments or they create data, the function should never assume that a variable is available in the enclosing environment or search path
- in my experience, I find it better to disconnect the connection explicitly immediately after the query instead of the next time a query is made; I will use `on.exit` for this, which "guarantees" that it will be disconnected even if something goes wrong with the query itself
- I really prefer shiny's "lazy" way of doing things: the query is not executed unless/until something needs to show it; in this app's case, that should be immediate, but there are times when the "lazy" execution of a `reactive` block is much preferred over the "eager" execution of an `observe` block
- the `executeQuery` function (fixed from above comments) can be defined outside of the `server` block, esp since I'm suggesting you take out the shiny-components from inside of it; doing this should help with console testing, too: the `executeQuery` function should work by itself on the console when not in shiny, making it easier to verify, develop, troubleshoot, etc

The standalone function:

```r
# Function to handle SQL query and result`your text`
executeQuery <- function(nhs, start, end) {
  on.exit(if (exists("con")) try(DBI::dbDisconnect(con), silent = TRUE), add = TRUE)
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
    Server = "SERVER",
    Database = "DATABASE",
    Trusted_Connection = "True"
  )

  query <- "
DECLARE @NHS_NUMBER VARCHAR(50), @START DATE, @END DATE;
SET @NHS_NUMBER = ?;
SET @START = ?;
SET @END = ?;

SELECT DISTINCT 
  [NHS_Number] = [A].[ID],
  [Setting] = 'Acute',
  [Event] = 'A&E Attendance'
  [Type] = 'A&E Attendance'
  [Date] = [A].[Date]
FROM Table [A]
WHERE [A].[ID] = @NHS_NUMBER
  AND CAST([A].[Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@START AS DATE) AND CAST(@END AS DATE)
"
  dbGetQuery(con, query, params = list(nhs, start, end))
  # con is auto-closed by the on.exit at the start of the function
}
```

And the `server` block, substantially reduced/simplified/reorganized:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Observe changes in input and manage database connection and result
  result <- eventReactive(input$submitBtn, {
    req(input$nhsnumber, input$startdate, input$enddate)
    tryCatch(
      executeQuery(input$nhsnumber, input$startdate, input$enddate),
      error = function(e) {
        warning("database query failed: ", conditionMessage(e))
        NULL
      }
    )
  })
    
  # Render the output (print)
  output$txtout <- renderPrint({
    req(result())
  })
  
  # Render the output (plot)
  # Render the output (print)
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(dat <- result())  # Ensure that result() is not NULL before attempting to print
    someplot( dat ) # you need to actually write this function, I don't know what you intend to plot
  })
}
```